# Why use a bitwise AND here?

Tags: java, partitioning, bitwise-operators

I was reading through the hadoop code and found this line in a partitioner.

`(key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks`

Why are they using the bitwise AND?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To remove the sign bit.  in the case that the hashCode is a negative number.
its like `Math.abs(key.hashCode())`

Comment: @chris-thompson i wonder what `Math.abs` does? it prob. does the same bitwise and.

Comment: `Math.abs` source code is a one-liner: `return (a < 0) ? -a : a;` where `a` is the `int` passed in.

Comment: They aren't actually doing `Math.abs` because of two's complement -- they just want any positive number (while respecting the probability distribution of the hashing function more or less).

Comment: `Math.abs()` has a strange habit to return a negative value on `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (namely this same value), since it is immune to the `-` operator. Thus the variant in the question is actually more secure, aside from being probably a bit faster, since no conditional is to be evaluated.

Comment: This also avoids a method call, although Math.abs() can potentially be inlined  by the Jit.

Comment: no, it's not like `abs()` because it just removes the sign bit, not negate or flip it. For example `-2 & Integer.MAX_VALUE` will return `2,147,483,646`, not 2